# confusing behavior of purrr::pmap with rlang; "to quote" or not to quote argument that is the Q

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rlang, tidyeval

I have a custom function where I am reading entered variables from a dataframe using `rlang`. This function works just fine **irrespective of** whether the arguments entered are quoted or unquoted. But, strangely enough, when this function is used with `purrr::pmap`, it works only if the argument is quoted.

So I have two questions:

1. Why does the function behavior this way?
2. How can I make a function using `rlang` such that I won't have to quote the arguments even if used in `purrr::pmap`?

Here is a minimal reprex that uses a simple function to highlight this issue:

```r
# loading the needed libraries
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)


# defining the function
tryfn <- function(data, x, y) {
  data <-
    dplyr::select(
      .data = data,
      x = !!rlang::enquo(x),
      y = !!rlang::enquo(y)
    )

  # creating a dataframe of means
  result_df <- data.frame(mean.x = mean(data$x), mean.y = mean(data$y))

  # return the dataframe
  return(result_df)
}

# without quotes (works!)
tryfn(iris, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)
#>     mean.x   mean.y
#> 1 5.843333 3.057333

# with quotes (works!)
tryfn(iris, "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
#>     mean.x   mean.y
#> 1 5.843333 3.057333

# pmap without quotes (doesn't work)
purrr::pmap(.l = list(
  data = list(iris, mtcars, ToothGrowth),
  x = list(Sepal.Length, wt, len),
  y = list(Sepal.Width, mpg, dose)
),
.f = tryfn)
#> Error in is.data.frame(.l): object 'Sepal.Length' not found

# pmap with quotes (works!)
purrr::pmap(.l = list(
  data = list(iris, mtcars, ToothGrowth),
  x = list("Sepal.Length", "wt", "len"),
  y = list("Sepal.Width", "mpg", "dose")
),
.f = tryfn)
#> [[1]]
#>     mean.x   mean.y
#> 1 5.843333 3.057333
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    mean.x   mean.y
#> 1 3.21725 20.09062
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>     mean.x   mean.y
#> 1 18.81333 1.166667
```

Created on 2018-05-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: The arguments you're supplying are passed to `list()` which is passed to `pmap()`. Neither of these functions does any quoting so R tries to evaluate the columns right away even though they are not there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was: R saw `Sepal.Length, wt, len` symbols so it tried to look in the current environment and evaluated them. Of course it resulted in errors as they were columns of a data frame. When you quoted them, R didn't try to evaluate and returned values as it saw those as strings.

If you replace `list` with `base::alist` or `dplyr::vars` or `rlang::exprs`, it should work

Note: as we already quote the inputs, we don't need to use `rlang::enquo` inside `tryfn` anymore.

```r
# loading the needed libraries
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)

# defining the function
tryfn <- function(data, x, y) {
  data <-
    dplyr::select(
      .data = data,
      x = !! x,
      y = !! y
    )

  # creating a data frame of means
  result_df <- data.frame(mean.x = mean(data$x), mean.y = mean(data$y))

  # return the data frame
  return(result_df)
}

# alist handles its arguments as if they described function arguments. 
# So the values are not evaluated, and tagged arguments with no value are 
# allowed whereas list simply ignores them. 

purrr::pmap(.l = list(
  data = list(iris, mtcars, ToothGrowth),
  x    = alist(Sepal.Length, wt, len),
  y    = alist(Sepal.Width, mpg, dose)
),
.f = tryfn)

#> [[1]]
#>     mean.x   mean.y
#> 1 5.843333 3.057333
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    mean.x   mean.y
#> 1 3.21725 20.09062
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>     mean.x   mean.y
#> 1 18.81333 1.166667


purrr::pmap(.l = list(
  data = list(iris, mtcars, ToothGrowth),
  x    = dplyr::vars(Sepal.Length, wt, len),
  y    = dplyr::vars(Sepal.Width, mpg, dose)
),
.f = tryfn)

#> [[1]]
#>     mean.x   mean.y
#> 1 5.843333 3.057333
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    mean.x   mean.y
#> 1 3.21725 20.09062
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>     mean.x   mean.y
#> 1 18.81333 1.166667

purrr::pmap(.l = list(
  data = list(iris, mtcars, ToothGrowth),
  x    = rlang::exprs(Sepal.Length, wt, len),
  y    = rlang::exprs(Sepal.Width, mpg, dose)
),
.f = tryfn)

#> [[1]]
#>     mean.x   mean.y
#> 1 5.843333 3.057333
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    mean.x   mean.y
#> 1 3.21725 20.09062
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>     mean.x   mean.y
#> 1 18.81333 1.166667
```

Created on 2018-05-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't with `purrr`, really.  The same behavior can be observed with:

```
list(Sepal.Length) # Error: object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

As I understand it, all of the magic with `!!`, `enquo`, and the like is available when you're passing arguments into a function *you have created*.  That's why it works to pass in the unquoted field names to `tryfn()` directly.

But with `pmap()`, you're putting the field names (`Sepal.Width`, `wt`, etc) in a `list` definition, and `list` doesn't like that - so `pmap` never even gets a chance to pass things into `tryfn` since your `list` barfs on definition.

Passing in your field names as strings works just fine, as `list` can accommodate that data type, and then `pmap` has the chance to map them into `tryfn()`.

Hadley's review of [quasiquotation with `dplyr`](https://github.com/hadley/adv-r/blob/master/Quotation.Rmd) might be useful to you.

To answer your second question:

> How can I make a function using rlang such that I won't have to quote the arguments even if used in purrr::pmap?

You can wrap your field names with `quo()` to avoid literally quoting them as strings, although I'm not sure that's much of an improvement:

```
purrr::pmap(.l = list(
  data = list(iris, mtcars, ToothGrowth),
  x = list(quo(Sepal.Length), quo(wt), quo(len)),
  y = list(quo(Sepal.Width), quo(mpg), quo(dose))
),
.f = tryfn) %>% 
  bind_rows(., .id="dataset")

  dataset    mean.x    mean.y
1       1  5.843333  3.057333
2       2  3.217250 20.090625
3       3 18.813333  1.166667
```